# how build AOSP 11 on macOS

Tags: android, android-source

I build AOSP Android 11 on MacBook Air M1, and have error

terminal log - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Fu09oS4puQkzq_G0eY-OxbFVJ3NnrPOxXC8V71LNDVM/edit?usp=sharing

I install  XCode, but it not work. MacOS 14.4 (Sonoma)
I try install MacOS SDK with command sudo port install MacOSX10.15.sdk
But I have problems with build AOSP Android 11 on macOS Sonoma 14.4 M1

Answer (score 0):

MacOS is no longer officially supported by Google since Android 11. https://source.android.com/docs/setup/start/requirements#os-requirements

However, I have had a bit of luck modifying the source code to add support wherever possible for Ventura 13.3 SDK back then on my M2 Pro MBP. For the error you have specifically mentioned in your question, soong build system needs to add support for modern macOS SDK versions. You can try the same with Sonoma 14.4 as well.

Refer to this commit and add 14.4:
https://github.com/rajatgupta1998/build_soong/commit/845c27d520c601b71565d7754c6e2efb541414f4